# Select field, presetting value

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, mysqli

As part of my project I have a page where all categories are listed. Each of them has a link to the single category page in order to modify it.

In the category page, I would to set the Category Name field as select field listing all categories pre-set on the selected category by default.
This example should clarify my question.

```
                      Category A
                      Category B
Selected Category --->Category C<--------Preset category opening the page
                      Category D
                      Category E
```

I implemented the code below and the preset category works. The difficulty I am finding is on the other categories listing. 
The category ID is passed to the single category page with this method:

```
<a href="categorie_scheda.php?cat_id='.$rows['0'].'">Link</a>
```

---category page---

```
<?php
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];  //cat ID captured here 
    include '../sys/conn.php';
    $category = mysqli_query ($conn, "(mysqli_query)") or die ("Query non valida: " . mysqli_error($conn));

    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($category, MYSQL_NUM);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

---html----

```
<label>Categorie</label>
<select class="form-control" name='category_list'>
    <option selected value=$cat_id><?php echo $array[1]; ?></option>

<?php 
    while ($listcat=mysqli_fetch_array($category)){
        echo '<option value="'.$listcat['0'].'"> '.$listcat['0'].' - '.$listcat['1'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Hope someone can help to get through.

Comment: Add the html attribute `selected` for your preselected option.

Comment: Progrock, i did but it's not enough. Still I don't have listed the  other categories stored in db

Comment: Can you clearly state the desired user action and the appropriate outcome.  I see no 'selected' attribute listed in the code given so far..

Comment: Where is the link code? Also `<option value="$cat_id">` is not PHP so that is the literal value, and will open you to XSS injections if just echoed. Fetching works on a closed connection?

Comment: @Progrock. Please note this screenshothttps://pasteboard.co/GGyMXTO.png that gives the idea. The preselect value is correctly displayed. The problem is that doesn't display others stored categories, making changes easier.

Comment: @chris85, I updated the code in the question but still the values are not listed in the select field as per attached image: https://pasteboard.co/GGyMXTO.png

Comment: Maybe something wrong in the while loop?

Comment: I don't think you can fetch after you closed the connection. That should free all the resources and remove the data. Id think that'd throw an error though, you get no errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in category page:

```
<?php
    $cat_id = intval($_GET['cat_id']);  //cat ID captured here. converting to int to avoid xss 
    include '../sys/conn.php';
    $category = mysqli_query ($conn, "(mysqli_query)") or die ("Query non valida: " . mysqli_error($conn));

    // replace $array = mysqli_fetch_array($category, MYSQL_NUM);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_all($category, MYSQL_NUM);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Your HTML should now go like this:

```
<label>Categorie</label>
<select class="form-control" name='category_list'>

<?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $listcat = $array[$i];
        echo '<option ' . ($listcat[0] == $cat_id ? 'selected ' : '') 
             . 'value="'.$listcat['0'].'"> ' 
             . $listcat['0'].' - '.$listcat['1'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

As noted in your comments, you are closing your connection without first saving your results. Either do it like I wrote above (with some minor bugfixes if they appear) or simply close your connection after everything is done.

Comment: Also `value=$cat_id>` won't work as OP wants (and open to XSS).

Comment: @chris85 true, i'm editing by simply converting to int.

Comment: i did change output of _selected_ line a bit, but this shouldn't be too much of a hassle

Comment: Still the same issue. Only the selected category is displayed and not the other categories.

Comment: then you either have only one ROW (was: column) or your query is doing something weird

Comment: It's weird because using  while loop: https://pastebin.com/dk4pQgYk,I get this result: https://pasteboard.co/GGzQZ2J.png that frankly I can't understand since the array has 10 values.

Comment: PROBLEM FOUND: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/pages/categories_form.php</b> on line <b>304</b><br />Array

Comment: cool :). you're aware i/we don't know what's in line 304 though